# Why I did not get Treading the Narrow Path achievement as Netherlands?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I was trying to get "Putting the Raid on the Medway to Shame" achievement but also thought that I will get "Treading the Narrow Path" if I just survive till 1945.

I was never in the war against Germany, but I did not get "Treading the Narrow Path" achievement neither in 1945, not in 1946.

Why? Maybe this because at some point I lost one of my mainland ports to Spain?

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: If you hover over the achievement you can see that you are not allowed to lose any starting territory. So if anyone event just for an hour occupied any of your starting core counties the achievement won't pop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like at least I do need "Man the guns" DLC... I guess that would answer 90% of the problems. Will wait for a discount on stream